# R Add column and amount for each renewal

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a add a new column based on a subset of data for each year an item renews.

[image: table]
[image: table png]

```
Name, Action, OrigAmt, Discount, NetAmt, Date
Aaa New       5         1        4    2014-07-04
Bbb Renewal   10        0       10    2015-03-02
Ccc Auto-Renew  8       0        8    2015-09-11
DDD Manual-Renew  14    5        9    2016-04-16
```

I’m trying to determine the average renewal dollar per year based on the Name.  So the end result should be 
Name  New(NetAmt)  RenewalAmt1   RenewalAmt2  (i.e. a name may renew year-over-year and I’d like to figure out the amount it renewed at)
(if a name does not renew it should not be included in the list)
It doesn't matter what type of renewal it is.

It is only one table i.e. I'm not merging data

Dplyr seems to be one everyone recommends and have tried ifelse statements but I can't seem to do the if it is a renewal than add a column but on the NetAmt for each year based on the Name

```
#attempt using dplyr
listin$renewed <- ifelse(listin$Action=="Renewal - Manual" | 
listin$Action=="Renewal - Auto" | listin$Action=="Transfer" , 1,0)
table(listin$renewed)
 listin %>%
  select(Name, Action, OrigAmt, Discounts, NetAmt) %>%
  filter(Action== "Registration") %>%
  mutate (listin$renewed ==1)
```

## another attempt using reshape

```
library (reshape2)
newlist <- melt(listin2, id=c("Name", "Action", "OrigAmt", "Discounts"))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `listin$renewed == 1` must be length 232 (the number of rows) or 
one, not 4831
```

Dataset link:  https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=D421AEB4A27DFF87%21118457&id=documents

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome, could you plase provide the result of dput() on a sample of your data, or could you please make a fake data set.

Comment: Thanks Bruno,  Data attached.  Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to pipe your data like, listin %>% filter(Actions %in% c("Renewal - Manual","Renewal - Auto","Transfer)), you can invert the operation with !